# Are questions that have answers in other questions duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043707/inaccurate-calculations-in-excel-vba), the best answer is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136860/how-to-check-dependencies-of-floats/9136907#9136907). (I linked in the comments)

Should I flag it as a duplicate question, even though the parent of that answer is not the same language, or is some other flag more appropriate, or some other action the best?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, they're not duplicate questions.

Answers are not considered when evaluating questions as duplicates, and in this specific instance, the questions only bear a passing resemblance.

Answer (score 2):

Your link is correct and does answer the question. I did flag that this question myself as a duplicate (though a duplicate to a different question than you did). I linked to another for *the same language* that the OP was asking about, but the ultimate response is the same.

I don't think it matters so much; if it is a duplicate problem and/or scenario with a duplicate answer, even with some a few differences, it's a duplicate.

Comment: "What is paper made out of
?" and "Where do the raw materials for log cabins come from?" are not duplicates, even though the answer for both is "trees."

Comment: @PopularDemand I'm pretty sure my post says `...if it's a duplicate problem/scenario/answer...` and not just `...if it's a duplicate answer...`. In other words: If it is a duplicate problem and/or scenario with a duplicate answer, then it's a duplicate.

Comment: That's entirely unfair. You edited your post after I wrote my comment. *At the time I commented*, the post said "if it's a duplicate problem/scenario/answer."

Comment: @PopularDemand (You'll see this comment was edited - I forgot to tag you) It's not unfair. I *did* edit the answer (the correction coming from my comment), but I quoted myself directly in the comment with the version you responded to. To quote my comment "*I'm pretty sure my post says* `...if it's a duplicate problem/scenario/answer...`"

Comment: There is no (relevant) difference between "if it's a duplicate problem/scenario/answer" and "if it's a duplicate answer." The latter is a subset of the former.

Comment: @PopularDemand And to that end, you are correct, hence my comment explanation and subsequent correction.

Comment: Hm. The first time I read your first comment, I thought you were saying I read it wrong and pointing at the later revision as evidence. And that the phrase with the slashes was different than the one without. Now I see that you meant that you saw the issue and corrected it. Sorry for wasting your time with this whole side conversation.

Comment: @PopularDemand Yeah, I probably could have worded it better. I was feeling a bit defensive myself. :-) No hard feelings!

Answer (score 0):

Because there's been previous frowning upon removing C# tags for general .NET questions asked by C# users, almost all C# questions can be asked again as VB.NET (and F# and C++/CLI) questions.

But in this case they're clearly not the same *Question*, so no, these are not the duplicates you're looking for. (Clearly there *is* another duplicate question to point to.)